# How to search on google map by city with gmaps4rails 2 and rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails2

I am using gmaps4rails v2 + rails 4 + ruby 2.0 
and i want to implement search functionality on map 
user will search by city and one marker should come on the map.

Is it possible with gem ? or what? any suggestion

Comment: Any luck with this in the last 5 months?

Comment: @Jake I did with ajax call... it is not possible with gem, i used j query auto-complete search box and used AJAX....Working fine ....

Comment: Thanks Rajesh.  I ended up copying the code from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) starting at the part with the search box.  But I wanted to find a more "Rails" way of doing it since I'm using the gem instead of just using the API directly.  Didn't like doing it both ways.